# Remote Desktop used for spying

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm concerned that someone who owned this computer, then gave it to me, is still able to connect to it and I'm worried about my security.

The person had a profile (account?) on the home screen recently when I started making enquiries of friends. It has now disappeared. How would they do that?

I checked the remote desktop app and saw it was enabled but my lack of computer IT knowledge stops me in my tracks and I don't know if that means the former owner is monitoring everything I do on this PC. How can I found out for sure? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some pretty essential facts are missing - what does the computer run? Why do you think its used for spying? If its a system you own properly, wiping it and reinstalling the OS would be a good option

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to hide accounts from being listed on the login screen. Those accounts can still be present and active however. If you use computer management and then click "Local Users and Groups" you can delete any accounts that you don't want/need.

In addition to removing any accounts you don't need, a password change on the remaining ones would be a good idea as well.

There could also be backdoor software hidden on the computer, so as Journeyman Geek suggested, wiping and reinstalling the OS is the only way to be sure.